# Jquery Form sending data the wrong way

Tags: javascript, jquery, express, ajaxsubmit

I'm using vue resource module to send POST requests, and jquery form plugin to send to the same routes, but with files.

This is my code

```
function sendWithoutFiles(data){
    return this.$http.post(link, data)
}
function sendWithFiles(data){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        jQuery('#form').ajaxSubmit({
            data: data,
            success: resolve,
            url: link
        })
    })
}

function send(data){
    var sendFunction = sendWithoutFiles;
    if(files)
        sendFunction = sendWithFiles;
    sendFunction({
        message: 'john',
        participants: [1, 50]
    }).then(function(res){
        console.log(res);
    })
}
```

Now, if I send them without files, it's perfect.
But when I do, the data arrives this way:

```
{
    message: ['john'],
    'participants[]': [1, 50]
}
```

I'm using express with multiparty like this:

```
app.post('*', function(req, res, next){
    var form = new multiparty.Form();
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files){
        req.uploadFiles = files;
        console.log(fields, req.body, "MID LOG");
        req.body = req.body || fields;
        next();
    })
})
```

In chrome network panel -> request payload
[image]
So I don't think it's something wrong with the multiparty module.

Am I doing something wrong with the jquery plugin ?

Comment: You are setting `if(files) sendFunction = sendWithoutFiles;`

Comment: that is a mistake just here on stack. in my code is correct. I updated my question. sorry

Comment: You are trying to post two different types
1.JSON
2. Multipart 
of data in the same request. That  is not possible I hope....?

Comment: and since when you can not post data + file at the same time ?